# Working with git

Tags: developer, upgrade

My development configuration:
I work on netbeans on my Windows.
My civicrm site runs on a remote ubuntu-server to which I can ssh and ftp.
I need to make some changes to civicrm-core.

I would like to work with netbeans' git feature (in order to graphically see history in netbeans, committing from the IDE etc.) so I cloned my fork using the IDE, and created a project that uploads the files to my servers.

Now my server has a folder which is like my fork, but of course I can't just symlink to it from `<drupal base>/sites/all/modules`. I need to add all the stuff missing, and right now I am copying (without overriding existing files) from a tarball I downloaded from sourceforge.
I guess there is a more programmatic way for doing that.
The help on [gitify](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/GitHub+for+CiviCRM) explains the opposite of what I am trying to achieve (it starts from a tarball and then connects to github).

thanks,

Roi
Modify message

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me that you are using two kinds of methods of deploying. You are using git and you are using ftp. Is that right?

I am also wondering why you need to directly change civicrm-core. Is there something missing and is there not another solution to find a solution for that specific need. Usually when you edit core files directly your maintance and updatability of your civicrm site gets more complicated.

Comment: You are right about the problems that I face when I change civicrm-core. I mainly need to render things differently to style the pages differently. Trying to base myself on [this fork](https://github.com/amilineni/civicrm-core/) which is explained [here](https://civicrm.org/blogs/teja/bootstrap-ui-one-small-step-civicrm). I need to work on the code because this fork is old.

git is the way you should work, AWS is where my site is hosted, and my PC is where I run my IDE, and where I want to control git.

Comment: What I would do then is to fork that repo on your own github page. And then use your personal github repo as a central point. From your local machine you push to this central repo and from youw AWS you pull from this repo

Comment: thanks. My question was how I create a workable civicrm directory from the clone i do from github. What script should I run that will envelope this with all needed in order to work in drupal.